# Setting up the workspace in GOLang?

Tags: linux, go, archlinux, gccgo

I can not in any way to customize the workspace in ArchLinux.

```
    form.go:6:24: ошибка: import file «github.com/google/gxui» not found
      "github.com/google/gxui"
                            ^
    form.go:7:35: ошибка: import file «github.com/google/gxui/drivers/gl» not found
      "github.com/google/gxui/drivers/gl"
                                       ^
    form.go:8:36: ошибка: import file «github.com/google/gxui/themes/dark» not found
      "github.com/google/gxui/themes/dark"
                                        ^
    form.go:11:25: ошибка: expected package
     func appMain(driver gxui.Driver) {
                             ^
    form.go:19:32: ошибка: expected package
      yesButton.OnClick(func(ev gxui.MouseEvent) {
                                    ^
    form.go:24:31: ошибка: expected package
      noButton.OnClick(func(ev gxui.MouseEvent) {
                                   ^
    form.go:12:11: ошибка: reference to undefined name «dark»
      theme := dark.CreateTheme(driver)
               ^
    form.go:34:27: ошибка: reference to undefined name «gxui»
      btnLayout.SetOrientation(gxui.Horizontal)
                               ^
    form.go:37:32: ошибка: reference to undefined name «gxui»
      layout.SetHorizontalAlignment(gxui.AlignCenter)
                                    ^
    form.go:38:30: ошибка: reference to undefined name «gxui»
      layout.SetVerticalAlignment(gxui.AlignMiddle)
                                  ^
    form.go:44:2: ошибка: reference to undefined name «gxui»
      gxui.EventLoop(driver)
      ^
    form.go:48:2: ошибка: reference to undefined name «gl»
      gl.StartDriver("", appMain)
      ^
```

Getting libraries:

```
    go get -u github.com/google/gxui
    go get -u github.com/google/gxui/drivers/gl
    go get -u github.com/google/gxui/themes/dark
```

Exhaust go env:

```
    [continue@LenovoG780 user]$ go env
    GOARCH="amd64"
    GOBIN=""
    GOCHAR="6"
    GOEXE=""
    GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
    GOHOSTOS="linux"
    GOOS="linux"
    GOPATH="/home/continue/go"
    GORACE=""
    GOROOT="/usr"
    GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0"
    CC="/usr/bin/gcc"
    GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
    CXX="/usr/bin/g++"
    CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Compilation:

```
    gccgo form.go -fuse-ld=gold -o form
```

What could be the problem?
    Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does **go run form.go** have the same problem?

Comment: Use the `go` tool to build the program. gccgo is a compiler, but doesn't know anything about the rest of the toolchain, or GOPATH. (and don't use gccgo unless you have a specific need for it)

Comment: [continue@LenovoG780 user]$ go build
# _/home/continue/~go/src/github.com/user
./form.go:44:7: ошибка: reference to undefined identifier «gxui.EventLoop»
  gxui.EventLoop(driver)
       ^
./form.go:34:11: ошибка: reference to undefined field or method «SetOrientation»
  btnLayout.SetOrientation(gxui.Horizontal)
           ^
./form.go:48:17: ошибка: argument 1 has incompatible type
  gl.StartDriver("", appMain)
                 ^
./form.go:48:5: ошибка: too man

Comment: [gxui](https://github.com/google/gxui) has many dependencies. It looks like some are missing. The readme says to run **go get -u github.com/google/gxui/...** (don't forget the ...) to get everything. By the way, gxui is unmaintained, alternatives are listed on the github page.

Comment: I am use <b>"get -u github.com/google/gxui/...</b>. 
The result is still the same

Comment: http://pastebin.com/T5iqCGVU

Error's/ at ge "get -u github.com/google/gxui/..."